# Power BI and JSON Issue (List on each Row Contains Multiple Records)

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I am working on trying to get Power BI to work with a CRM JSON API.

Example:

```
    {
"items": [
    {
        "FieldName 1": FieldData,
        "FieldName 2": FieldData,
        "FieldName n": FieldData,
        "userDefinedFields": [
            {"Name":"UDF 1", "value": FieldData},
            {"Name":"UDF 2", "value": FieldData},
            ...
            {"Name":"UDF n", "value": FieldData}
        ]
    }
],
```

Updated

```
    {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "actualBilledHours": 0,
      "actualHours": 1.5,
      "changeOrdersBudget": null,
      "changeOrdersRevenue": 0,
      "companyID": 0,
      "companyOwnerResourceID": null,
      "completedDateTime": null,
      "completedPercentage": 1,
      "contractID": null,
      "createDateTime": "2012-08-31T00:00:00Z",
      "creatorResourceID": 4,
      "department": null,
      "description": "",
      "duration": 61,
      "endDateTime": "2013-01-04T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedSalesCost": 0,
      "estimatedTime": 80.25,
      "extProjectNumber": "",
      "extProjectType": null,
      "impersonatorCreatorResourceID": null,
      "laborEstimatedCosts": 0,
      "laborEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "laborEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "lastActivityDateTime": "2017-03-17T08:58:25.107Z",
      "lastActivityPersonType": 1,
      "lastActivityResourceID": 29682924,
      "opportunityID": null,
      "organizationalLevelAssociationID": null,
      "originalEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "projectCostEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "projectCostsBudget": 0,
      "projectCostsRevenue": 0,
      "projectLeadResourceID": 4,
      "projectName": "xxxxxxx",
      "projectNumber": "P20120831.0001",
      "projectType": 4,
      "purchaseOrderNumber": "",
      "sgda": 0,
      "startDateTime": "2012-11-05T00:00:00Z",
      "status": 0,
      "statusDateTime": "2017-03-17T08:58:00Z",
      "statusDetail": "",
      "userDefinedFields": [
        {
          "name": " UDF1",
          "value": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF2",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF3",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Project Type",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF5",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF6",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "actualBilledHours": 0,
      "actualHours": 0,
      "changeOrdersBudget": null,
      "changeOrdersRevenue": 0,
      "companyID": 0,
      "companyOwnerResourceID": null,
      "completedDateTime": null,
      "completedPercentage": 0,
      "contractID": null,
      "createDateTime": "2016-02-03T00:00:00Z",
      "creatorResourceID": 29682885,
      "department": 29683480,
      "description": "xxxxxxxx",
      "duration": 350,
      "endDateTime": "2017-01-23T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedSalesCost": 0,
      "estimatedTime": 27,
      "extProjectNumber": "",
      "extProjectType": null,
      "impersonatorCreatorResourceID": null,
      "laborEstimatedCosts": 0,
      "laborEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "laborEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "lastActivityDateTime": "2017-03-17T08:59:22.767Z",
      "lastActivityPersonType": 1,
      "lastActivityResourceID": 29682888,
      "opportunityID": null,
      "organizationalLevelAssociationID": 10,
      "originalEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "projectCostEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "projectCostsBudget": 0,
      "projectCostsRevenue": 0,
      "projectLeadResourceID": 29682885,
      "projectName": "xxxxx",
      "projectNumber": "P20160203.0001",
      "projectType": 5,
      "purchaseOrderNumber": "",
      "sgda": 0,
      "startDateTime": "2016-02-09T00:00:00Z",
      "status": 0,
      "statusDateTime": "2017-03-17T08:59:00Z",
      "statusDetail": "",
      "userDefinedFields": [
        {
          "name": " UDF1",
          "value": "No"
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF2",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF3",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Project Type",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF5",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF6",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "actualBilledHours": 0,
      "actualHours": 22,
      "changeOrdersBudget": null,
      "changeOrdersRevenue": 0,
      "companyID": 235,
      "companyOwnerResourceID": null,
      "completedDateTime": "2016-12-13T11:10:38.883Z",
      "completedPercentage": 100,
      "contractID": null,
      "createDateTime": "2016-02-22T00:00:00Z",
      "creatorResourceID": 29682898,
      "department": 29683471,
      "description": "xxxxxx",
      "duration": 25,
      "endDateTime": "2016-03-17T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedSalesCost": 0,
      "estimatedTime": 30,
      "extProjectNumber": "xxxxxx",
      "extProjectType": null,
      "impersonatorCreatorResourceID": null,
      "laborEstimatedCosts": 0,
      "laborEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "laborEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "lastActivityDateTime": "2016-12-13T11:10:41.56Z",
      "lastActivityPersonType": 1,
      "lastActivityResourceID": 29682898,
      "opportunityID": null,
      "organizationalLevelAssociationID": 12,
      "originalEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "projectCostEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "projectCostsBudget": 0,
      "projectCostsRevenue": 0,
      "projectLeadResourceID": 29682907,
      "projectName": "xxxxxxx",
      "projectNumber": "P20160222.0001",
      "projectType": 5,
      "purchaseOrderNumber": "xxxxxxxx",
      "sgda": 0,
      "startDateTime": "2016-02-22T00:00:00Z",
      "status": 5,
      "statusDateTime": "2016-12-13T11:10:38.883Z",
      "statusDetail": "\r\nStatus was set to Complete",
      "userDefinedFields": []
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "actualBilledHours": 0,
      "actualHours": 0,
      "changeOrdersBudget": null,
      "changeOrdersRevenue": 0,
      "companyID": 0,
      "companyOwnerResourceID": null,
      "completedDateTime": "2020-04-02T10:22:28.463Z",
      "completedPercentage": 100,
      "contractID": null,
      "createDateTime": "2016-02-22T00:00:00Z",
      "creatorResourceID": 29682898,
      "department": null,
      "description": "",
      "duration": 1,
      "endDateTime": "2016-02-28T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedSalesCost": 0,
      "estimatedTime": 0,
      "extProjectNumber": "xxxx",
      "extProjectType": null,
      "impersonatorCreatorResourceID": null,
      "laborEstimatedCosts": 0,
      "laborEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "laborEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "lastActivityDateTime": "2020-04-02T10:22:28.527Z",
      "lastActivityPersonType": 1,
      "lastActivityResourceID": 29682966,
      "opportunityID": null,
      "organizationalLevelAssociationID": 4,
      "originalEstimatedRevenue": 0,
      "projectCostEstimatedMarginPercentage": 0,
      "projectCostsBudget": 0,
      "projectCostsRevenue": 0,
      "projectLeadResourceID": 29682898,
      "projectName": "xxxxxxxx",
      "projectNumber": "P20160222.0002",
      "projectType": 5,
      "purchaseOrderNumber": "xxxxxxxx",
      "sgda": 0,
      "startDateTime": "2016-02-28T00:00:00Z",
      "status": 5,
      "statusDateTime": "2020-04-02T10:22:00Z",
      "statusDetail": "Status was set to Complete",
      "userDefinedFields": [
        {
          "name": " UDF1",
          "value": "No"
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF2",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF3",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Project Type",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF5",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": " UDF6",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  "pageDetails": {
    "count": 500,
    "requestCount": 500,
    "prevPageUrl": null,
    "nextPageUrl": "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=%7b%22pageSize%22%3a500%2c%22previousIds%22%3a%5b3%5d%2c%22nextIds%22%3a%5b592%5d%7d&search=%7b%22filter%22%3a%5b%7b%22id%22%3a%22gte%22%2c%22value%22%3a%220%22%7d%5d%7d"
  }
}
```

From - https://ww1.autotask.net/help/developerhelp/Content/APIs/REST/API_Calls/REST_Basic_Query_Calls.htm?Highlight=search

The code I have currently is:

```
    let

searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),

initData = initReq[items],

//We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records,

//then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then

//create a table from those records

gather = (data as record, uri) =>

let
//get new offset from active uri
newOffset = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[count][prevPageUrl][nextPageUrl],

//build new uri using the original uri so we dont append offsests
newUri = baseuri & "&count=" & newOffset,

//get new req & data
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)) ,
newdata = newReq[items] ,

//add that data to rolling aggregate
data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

//if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data

check = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable(newReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then @gather (data , newUri) else data

in check,

//before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
outputList = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable (initReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then gather( initData , baseuri) else initData ,

//then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(expand, "userDefinedFields", "userDefinedFields - Copy")
in
    #"Duplicated Column"
```

I'm really struggling to create code which will look through the 'items' colum then go in to the list and for each record grab the header, value and put back on the orgional row it was found. Some records are emptyso I need to have some error corrections.

Unfortuntly I cant share the raw JSON for many reasons including not finding a way to display in Power BI but I have included an example above.

I apprciate any help any one offers here.

Thanks

Terran

EDIT

Mashup of code so far

```
let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]} 

//searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""isActive"":""eq"",""value"":""true""}]",
//searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""isActive"":""eq"",""value"":""true""}]",
//searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"": ""exist"",""field"": ""id""}]",

searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net//atservicesrest/v1.0/Resources/query?search=" & searchParam,


initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),

initData = initReq[items],

//We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records,

//then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then

//create a table from those records

gather = (data as record, uri) =>

let
//get new offset from active uri
newOffset = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[count][prevPageUrl][nextPageUrl],

//build new uri using the original uri so we dont append offsests
newUri = baseuri & "&count=" & newOffset,

//get new req & data
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)) ,
newdata = newReq[items] ,

//add that data to rolling aggregate
data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

//if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data

check = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable(newReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then @gather (data , newUri) else data

in check,

//before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
outputList = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable (initReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then gather( initData , baseuri) else initData ,

pageDetails = outputList[pageDetails],
Part1=Table.FromRecords({pageDetails}),

//then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source[items], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),

expand = Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
#"Expanded userDefinedFields" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Expand, "userDefinedFields"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded userDefinedFields", "name", each try [userDefinedFields][name] otherwise null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "value", each try [userDefinedFields][value] otherwise null),
Part2 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"userDefinedFields"}),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Part1) & Table.ToColumns(Part2) ,
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) & Table.ColumnNames(Part2)),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(custom2,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) )

in #"Filled Down"
```

v2

```
let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]}

// searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Resources/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),

initData = initReq[items],

//We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records,

//then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then

//create a table from those records

gather = (data as record, uri) =>

let
//get new offset from active uri
newOffset = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[count][prevPageUrl][nextPageUrl],

//build new uri using the original uri so we dont append offsests
newUri = baseuri & "&count=" & newOffset,

//get new req & data
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)) ,
newdata = newReq[items] ,

//add that data to rolling aggregate
data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

//if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data

check = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable(newReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then @gather (data , newUri) else data

in check,

//before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
outputList = if Table.Contains ( Record.ToTable (initReq) , [Name = "count"] ) = true then gather( initData , baseuri) else initData ,

//then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Updated v4 code now with over 500 records working

```
let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]}

// searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
// {"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]}
searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxx",
                #"UserName"=" xxxxxx ",
                #"Secret"=" xxxxxx ",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),
    initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri 
            newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
            //get new req & data
            newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)),
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    outputList = if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, baseuri),
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(expand,{{"id", Order.Ascending}}),

// insert record code here
    // let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json")), <---- change this source to the table and run
    // pageDetails = Source[pageDetails],    
    // Part1=Table.FromRecords({pageDetails}),
    // #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source[items], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
    // ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
    // Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
    // #"Expanded userDefinedFields" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Expand, "userDefinedFields"),
    // #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded userDefinedFields", "name", each try [userDefinedFields][name] otherwise null),
    // #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "value", each try [userDefinedFields][value] otherwise null),    
    // Part2 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"userDefinedFields"}),
    // custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Part1) & Table.ToColumns(Part2) ,
    // custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) & Table.ColumnNames(Part2)),
    // #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(custom2,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) )
    // in #"Filled Down"


    #"Duplicated Projects Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "id", "id - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Ops Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Projects Column", "opportunityID", "opportunityID - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Contracts Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Ops Column", "contractID", "contractID - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Contracts Column",{{"id - Copy", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"opportunityID - Copy", type text}, {"contractID - Copy", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/Projects/ProjectDetail.mvc/ProjectDetail?gridConfiguration=Outline&initialContentPage=Summary&projectId=" ,[#"id - Copy"]})),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "idURLProjects"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "idURLOps", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/CRM/OpportunityDetail.mvc?opportunityId=" ,[#"opportunityID - Copy"]})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "idURLContracts", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/contracts/views/contractView.asp?contractID=" ,[#"contractID - Copy"]}))
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```

Final v5 Working Code

```
// https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Handling-a-Paginated-API-with-Prebuilt-Next-Page-URI-in-Response/m-p/1777718#M53393
// https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/extracting-data-from-lists-and-records-in-power-query
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525106/power-bi-and-json-issue-list-on-each-row-contains-multiple-records
// #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Custom", each try Record.Feild( [userDefinedFields]{0}, "Main Connectivity Deliverable" ) otherwise "")
// https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/Projects/ProjectDetail.mvc/ProjectDetail?gridConfiguration=Outline&initialContentPage=Summary&projectId=576
// https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/CRM/OpportunityDetail.mvc?opportunityId=16155
// https://ww4.autotask.net/contracts/views/contractView.asp?contractID=29683986
// https://www.postman.com/bold-comet-4756/workspace/autotask/documentation/1703604-2c1a0b29-c44a-4f48-8cd0-359b1a54a27f
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900646/converting-dynamic-query-to-direct-query-in-the-context-of-a-paginated-records-s
// https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging={"pageSize": 500,"previousIds": [3],"nextIds": [593]}&search={"filter":[{"op":"gte","field": "id","value": "0"}]}
// https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Expanding-List-of-Records-into-Columns/m-p/1348803#M579607


let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]}

// searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
// {"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]}
searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),
    initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri 
            newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
            //get new req & data
            newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)),
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    outputList = if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, baseuri),
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(expand,{{"id", Order.Descending}}),

    // Customermising the sheet
    #"Duplicated Projects Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "id", "id - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Ops Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Projects Column", "opportunityID", "opportunityID - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Contracts Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Ops Column", "contractID", "contractID - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Contracts Column",{{"id - Copy", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"opportunityID - Copy", type text}, {"contractID - Copy", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/Projects/ProjectDetail.mvc/ProjectDetail?gridConfiguration=Outline&initialContentPage=Summary&projectId=" ,[#"id - Copy"]})),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "idURLProjects"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "idURLOps", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/Mvc/CRM/OpportunityDetail.mvc?opportunityId=" ,[#"opportunityID - Copy"]})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "idURLContracts", each Text.Combine({"https://ww4.autotask.net/contracts/views/contractView.asp?contractID=" ,[#"contractID - Copy"]})),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Main Connectivity Deliverable", each List.Select([userDefinedFields], each Record.FieldNames(_){0} = "name"){0}[value]),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Project Type UDF", each List.Select([userDefinedFields], each Record.FieldNames(_){0} = "name"){1}[value])
in
    #"Added Custom4"
```

Comment: That is not a valid JSON snippet, which makes doing anything to help you hard

Comment: Hi @horseyride - I have manged to obtain a cleaned up extract of JSON - I hope that is enough for some help. I've continued to work on the problem but its not an idea API. Thanks T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fully process your JSON

```
let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json")),
pageDetails = Source[pageDetails],
Part1=Table.FromRecords({pageDetails}),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source[items], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
#"Expanded userDefinedFields" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Expand, "userDefinedFields"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded userDefinedFields", "name", each try [userDefinedFields][name] otherwise null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "value", each try [userDefinedFields][value] otherwise null),
Part2 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"userDefinedFields"}),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Part1) & Table.ToColumns(Part2) ,
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) & Table.ColumnNames(Part2)),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(custom2,Table.ColumnNames(Part1) )
in #"Filled Down"
```

hoping that helps

Comment: Thanks... I am trying to absorb what you have shared and will come back soon hence the code above.  One of the big issues I had with the API was it pagnated and very spefic calls to get the next pages. I apprciate the time you have took so far. T

Comment: Thats my plan... I'm not a coder by trade so may take a little while longer than others but I will defo share the results here when working. T

Comment: Still to fully test... but not forgotten - biggets issue I'm having is using the JSON from the download rather than a local file as well as diffrent API formats & the multipage call ;) - EDIT I've added my none working code so far to the first post... I know its not great and this is a horrible API...

Comment: I managed to crack the 500 issue but looking at your code can you talk me through it ? I'm looking at the source to be the table (Autotask_Projects) and the feild but userDefinedFields rather than the raw JSON. I'm also getting token identifier expected with your code but it looks good to me ?

Comment: As a passing note I've also tried a custom colum of "Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Deliverable UDF", each Record.Field([userDefinedFields][Record],"Deliverable"))" with little luck either.

Comment: Got it working using List.Select - I want to thank HorseyRider and those other sites (links in my code) that got me working. I hope this helps others in the future. Terran

Comment: thats a long list of things you went through to get this working. Good job